# how to make mouse events work as a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, mouseevent

I  have to implement three types of mouse events in a sequence.Each mouse event is allowed only certain number of times.So, I initialized a variable and put it like this

```
int a = 0;
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (a < 2)
     {
          // a little code here  
          //this makes mouse up to work for 2 times.
     }
}
private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (a > 1 && a <= 3)
    {


                c[f] = e.X;
                d[f] = e.Y;
                a++;
                f++;


    } 
}    
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (a > 3 && a < 11)
    {
        //some more code
        //this makes MouseClick to work for 7 times
    }
}
```

now i want to run the last two events again, when ever i press a button.Please give me some ideas how can make them run again.

I tried to implement this one but didnot work.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = 2;// I thought it would set a=2 and the MouseDoubleClick would be implemented but my assumption proved to be wrong.
}
```

Comment: not sure why you would want to. If you need something to occur x times within a single even, then code it that way. Attempting to force an event multiple times seems a little illogical.

Comment: I can make an event run x times,but the problem is the sequence in which the events occur is important for me,until and unless you know about my project you feel it illogical.

Answer (score 3):

You can just explicitly call the Event Methods passing in null values:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = 2;
    pictureBox1_MouseClick(null,null);
    pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(null,null);

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(a > 1 && a <=3)
    {
        if(e!=null)
        {
            c[f] = e.X;
            d[f] = e.Y;
            a++;
            f++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will stop the error from occurring but when the event method is fired from the button2_Click method it will not actually do anything as the values for e.X and e.Y will be null.

You will need to come up with a different way of solving this problem as I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am getting Null exception error if i implement this way...please check my  code as i have  edit some part of it. Particularly Mouse Double Click ,since there is a code which doesnot accept null values.

Comment: You would get that because you are trying to use parameters from the Mouse Event Args which was not the original problem. You are trying to set the co-ordinates by doing this: c[f] = e.X, but e will be null when picutreBox1_MouseDoubleClick(null,null) is fired.

Comment: You can check for null, as I have done in my edit. But this defeats the purpose of what you are trying to do I assume.

Comment: Please provide your contact or mail Id i will clear explain my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

You can specialize whatever object you're listening to events from. In your case the PictureBox object I guess.
As a convenience it's a convention to create protected virtual methods to broadcast events. This allows you to override and add additional behavior when events occur.

For example:

```
public class FooPicbox : PictureBox {

   protected override void OnMouseDown( MouseEventArgs e ) {
      base.OnMouseDown( e );
      /* Insert code here */
      /* Example: */
      base.OnMouseUp( e );
      base.OnMouseClick( e );
   }
}
```

Then, when the MouseDown event occurs, it also broadcasts the two other events.